# How to use loops and average in Java

Tags: java, loops

My program is supposed to find the average of female, male, and total average GPA of students. And also total female, male, and total students.  First it asks if the student is male or female.  If you choose male it does the loop, but after it ends. I want my program to go straight into the next choice. Example if you choose male the you'll input female and visa versa.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class practice {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    int maleCount=0, femaleCount=0, totalStudents;
    double GPA, mTotal = 0, mAverage, fTotal = 0, fAverage, allAverage;

    System.out.println("Is the student Male or Female?");
    System.out.println("Enter M for male or F for female.");
    String student = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("Enter GPA");
    GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();


    if (student.equals("M")) {
      while (GPA >=0) {
        mTotal = mTotal + GPA;
        maleCount++;
        GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }
    }

    if (student.equals("F")) {
      while (GPA >=0) {
        fTotal = fTotal + GPA;
        femaleCount++;
        GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }
    }

    mAverage = mTotal/maleCount;
    fAverage = fTotal/femaleCount;
    allAverage = mTotal + fTotal;
    totalStudents = maleCount + femaleCount;

    System.out.println("Total MALE students: " + maleCount);
    System.out.println("Total FEMALE students: " + femaleCount);
    System.out.println("Total STUDENTS: " + totalStudents);
    System.out.println("Total MALE GPA: " + mTotal);
    System.out.println("Total FEMALE GPA: " + fTotal);
    System.out.println("Total MALE Average GPA: " + mAverage);
    System.out.println("Total average: " + allAverage);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.  2) It is best to form an explicit question (and add a '?' at the end).  What is your question?

Comment: Oh, I just spotted the question in the title.  Again, please be sure to add a '?'.

Answer (score 2):

> How to use loops and average in Java?

Well, pretty much as in the code in your question, I'd say.  Just add a loop around the part that needs a loop, and figure out how you are going to end the looping.

The other problems that leap out at me are:

- You seem to be accepting the input in a strange order.
- You are calculating `allAverage` incorrectly.  Just look at the code again.  The problem should be obvious.

---

Actually, one of the difficulties with answering this Question is that it is not at all clear how the program as written is supposed to behave.  And we can't infer that from what you've shown us.  'Cos what you've written obviously doesn't work ... from a usability perspective.

If you don't understand and can't explain the requirements properly, there is not much chance that you will be able to implement them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my code sorry for it being unclear.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class practice 
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
int maleCount=0, femaleCount=0, totalStudents, count = 0;
double GPA, mTotal = 0, mAverage, fTotal = 0, fAverage, allAverage;

System.out.println("Is the student Male or Female?");
System.out.println("Enter M for male or F for female.");
String student = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();


do{
  System.out.println("Enter GPA " + student);
  GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
if (student.equals("M"))
{
while (GPA >=0)
{
    mTotal = mTotal + GPA;
    maleCount++;
    GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
student = "F";
}


else if (student.equals("F"))
{
    while (GPA >=0)
    {
        fTotal = fTotal + GPA;
        femaleCount++;
        GPA = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
    student = "M";
}
}
while (++count < 2);


mAverage = mTotal/maleCount;
fAverage = fTotal/femaleCount;
totalStudents = maleCount + femaleCount;
allAverage = (mTotal + fTotal)/totalStudents;



System.out.println("Total MALE students: " + maleCount);
System.out.println("Total FEMALE students: " + femaleCount);
System.out.println("Total STUDENTS: " + totalStudents);
System.out.println("Total MALE GPA: " + mTotal);
System.out.println("Total FEMALE GPA: " + fTotal);
System.out.println("Total average: " + allAverage);
```

}